# Google analytic history after website update

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

We just updated our website to the most recent WordPress version and switched hosting companies.  Sometime during or after the switch over, our Google Analytics plugin was deactivated.  I have since re-activated it but we are unable to see the history of the analytics prior to the switch over.  Is there a way to get that history back?

Comment: My guess is when you added the code again to your site you are using a different google analytics account.   The data wont disappear unless you delete it from google analytics.  You have however lost the data from the time when the plugin was not installed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does not pertain to coding and thus should be posted in another forum, like Webmasters.

Answer (score 1):

In general, there is no way to get hold of Google Analytics data that you didn't track at the time. There is also no way to transfer data from one account, property or view to another.

If you had Google Analytics enabled on your site before, then the data that it gathered at that point will still be kept, so long as you remember the log-in details from the time and haven't deleted the account, removed yourself from it, or similar.

However there's no way to migrate it from an old Google Analytics account to a new one, so if the problem here is that you're not seeing your old data on the new account, then this is caused by the fact that the two trackers had different unique IDs, and there's no way to rectify this.